# create a matrix by applying user defined function to a set of vectors

Tags: r

I have this function to measure the similarity of a pair of dictionaries.

```
similarity_index <- function(dix1, dix2) {
  nc <- length(intersect(dix1,dix2)) 
  n1 <- length(dix1) 
  n2 <- length(dix2)
  return(nc / sqrt(n1*n2))
}

dix1 = c("a","b","c")
dix2 = c("e","f","g")
dix3 = c("a","f","g")

similarity_index(dix1,dix2)
similarity_index(dix2,dix3)
similarity_index(dix1,dix3)
```

Is there a simple way I can create a matrix by crossing these dictionaries with my function? I'm looking for a dix / dix matrix (in this case 3 rows by 3 cols), like this:

```
          dix1  dix2  dix3
dix1    1       0       0,3
dix2    0       1       0,6
dix3    0,3   0,6     1
```

I'll later use this matrix for hclustering or corplot.

Comment: Each of the similarity_index returns a single value as output.  Not clear what you expect as a matrix?  is it a single column matrix ?

Comment: i expect a dix x dix matrix (in this example: 3 rows / 3 columns) with the value from the function

Comment: i just edited to include the expected output. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `outer`

```
v1 <- paste0('dix', 1:3)
out <- outer(v1, v1, Vectorize(function(x, y) similarity_index(get(x), get(y))))
dimnames(out) <- list(v1, v1)
out
#          dix1      dix2      dix3
#dix1 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333
#dix2 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667
#dix3 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000
```